# pull from session user info

Tags: php, mysqli

ok I have a user login that uses email address and password when they login I want to pull there session data

like username and anything else from there record

I use this

```
<?php 

                            if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {

                            echo $_SESSION['email'];

                        }
                        ?>
```

it works and pulls there email address but how do I get there username? I tried changing email to username and nothing shows

my login setup

```
/* login functions */


function login_user($email, $password, $remember)
{
    $sql = "SELECT user_pwd, uid FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "' AND active = 1";

    $result = query($sql);

    if (row_count($result) == 1) {

        $row = fetch_array($result);

        $db_password = $row['user_pwd'];

        if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {

            if ($remember == "on") {                

                setcookie("email", $email, time() + 86400,'/');

            }

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}


/* User Logged in Function */


function logged_in(){

    if (isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email'])) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: replace "echo $_SESSION['email'];" with var_dump($_SESSION);. That will let you know what all information you have access to in the session. If you want something that's not there, then you're going to have to find where the session is created and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make small changes in login_user() function.

```
 function login_user($email, $password, $remember)
{
   $sql = "SELECT user_pwd, uid, username FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "' AND active = 1";

   $result = query($sql);

   if (row_count($result) == 1) {

    $row = fetch_array($result);

    $db_password = $row['user_pwd'];

    if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {

        if ($remember == "on") {                

            setcookie("email", $email, time() + 86400,'/');

        }

        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }

    return true;
  } else {

    return false;
   }
}
```

Now you can use below code to get username in session. But make sure you must have **username** field in **users** table.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
```